# Condition not working inside eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I need to make a simple events listener, which will change the **1st value element** of the `input.value` each time, when the button will be clicked. To solve this problem, I wrote a simple condition inside the function `menuide` for **onclick listener**. But for some reason it's only works once when listening to an event, although every time an event triggers, it should work and fulfil one of the conditions.

Can anyone explain to me why my function change `input.value[0]` only once of all clicks?

```js
function menuide() {
  menu.classList.toggle('ul-wide');

  var arr = 'b';
  var value = Array.prototype.slice.call(inp.value);
  var newValue = value.splice(1);

  if (inp.value[0] != 'b') {
    inp.value = arr + newValue.join('');
  }

  if (inp.value[0] == 'b') {
    inp.value[0] == 'a' + newValue.join('');;
  }
}

inp.addEventListener('click', menuide);
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}

.ul-wide {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="inp" value="a click on me to make a wonder! :)"></input>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>Smile</li>
  <li>Happy</li>
  <li>Dog</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your `inp` variable isn't defined in this context and must be a property of the global variable `window`. The value of `inp` may be altered. Your second `if` will always be true because if the value of `inp` do not start with a "b", you change its value with `arr + newValue.join('')`. As `arr` contains "b"... You could avoid that by replacing `if (inp.value[0] == 'b')` by an `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is few errors in your code:
1. Instead of `inp.value[0] == 'a' + newValue.join('');;`
you probably want to write  `inp.value = 'a' + newValue.join('');`
2. Also before second if you need to add `else`

```
function menuide() {
    menu.classList.toggle('ul-wide');

    var arr = 'b';
    var value = Array.prototype.slice.call(inp.value);
    var newValue = value.splice(1);

    if (inp.value[0] !== 'b') {
        inp.value = arr + newValue.join('');
    } else if (inp.value[0] === 'b') {
        inp.value = 'a' + newValue.join('');
    }
}
```

Comment: The `else if` could be an `else` because the second `if` will always be true if the first `if` is false.

Comment: @vadim thank you! You show me my automistakes in several strings! ) Cheers!

Comment: I'm happy to help. Please mark answer as correct. This will help others to find it.